# What's the pandas equivalent of R take a subset based on a logical condition?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, logical-operators

I want to compute the equivalent of this from r to pandas:

```
df$received[df$gender == 'F']
```

In pandas, if I use:

```
df['received'][df['gender'] == 'F']
```

it doesn't work.

Or if I try:

```
df['received'] & df['gender'] == 'F'
```

it gives me: `unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'`

Comment: sorry are you after `df.loc[df['gender'] == 'F', 'received']`?

Comment: This is called **logical-indexing**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['gender'] == 'F', 'received']
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender':['F','M','F'], 'received':[10,20,50]})
print (df)
  gender  received
0      F        10
1      M        20
2      F        50

print (df.loc[df['gender'] == 'F', 'received'])
0    10
2    50
Name: received, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hmm.strange...I have 3000 records with 'F' and 'M'.1500 of them is 'F'.The above solution gives me 3000 records instead of 1500.But in your example it works.

Comment: No, whitespace.Just `df.loc[df['gender'] == 'F', 'received']`

Comment: It seems problem in data.

Comment: The data seems ok.And using R `df$received[df$gender == 'F']` returns 1500 fields.Very weird..Anyway, I will accept your answer since it seems to be right